# Align lines and bars in a mixed chart

Tags: javascript, alignment, bar-chart, chart.js, linechart

I'm working on a mixed chart where I need to plot a stepped linechart on a barchart. The datapoints in my linechart are aligned in the middle of a bar by default like this:

[image: Mixed chart]

I want to make the start of the line to align with the beginning of the bar like so:

[image: Situation I want]

I've been through the documentation of Chartjs but i can't find a way to make the line start at the beginning of my bar.

I setup a little example to explain my problem a little bit further:

```js
var opc = $("#chart");
var myChart = new Chart(opc, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'],
    datasets: [{
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Bar Component',
      data: [10, 20, 30],
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      steppedLine: true,
      label: 'Line Component',
      data: [25, 5, 20],
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 0, // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
          // OR //
          beginAtZero: true // minimum value will be 0.
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the link to a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7yheenc6/1/

Answer (score 1):

I went through the documentation but couldn't find anything on how to fix this. I though it would be relatively simple to fix it through code, boy was I wrong, anyway I got it working, you need to manually change the code in chart.js source file. Here is the line you need to change

**Before([chart.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.bundle.js)):**

Line number: 12891

```
function lineToPoint(previousPoint, point) {
                var vm = point._view;
                if (point._view.steppedLine === true) {
                    ctx.lineTo(point._view.x, previousPoint._view.y);
                    ctx.lineTo(point._view.x, point._view.y);               
                } else if (point._view.tension === 0) {
                    ctx.lineTo(vm.x, vm.y);
                } else {
                    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
                        previousPoint._view.controlPointNextX,
                        previousPoint._view.controlPointNextY,
                        vm.controlPointPreviousX,
                        vm.controlPointPreviousY,
                        vm.x,
                        vm.y
                    );
                }
            }
```

**After(chart.js):**

Line number: 12891

```
function lineToPoint(previousPoint, point) {
    var vm = point._view;
    if (point._view.steppedLine === true) {
        ctx.lineTo((point._view.x - previousPoint._view.x)/2 + previousPoint._view.x, previousPoint._view.y);
        ctx.lineTo((point._view.x - previousPoint._view.x)/2 + previousPoint._view.x, point._view.y);   
        ctx.lineTo(point._view.x, point._view.y);           
    } else if (point._view.tension === 0) {
        ctx.lineTo(vm.x, vm.y);
    } else {
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            previousPoint._view.controlPointNextX,
            previousPoint._view.controlPointNextY,
            vm.controlPointPreviousX,
            vm.controlPointPreviousY,
            vm.x,
            vm.y
        );
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/7yheenc6/4/

**Output:**

[image: chart.js mod]

I hope this solves your issue :)